# InsertTokensAfter() How to Add New Token after a. Existing SyntaxToken c# Roslyn

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis, codefixprovider

I want to add a `<T>` after `DeserializeObject` like `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json)`
Below is how I'm trying to achieve it

```
var desiToken = node.DescendantTokens().Where(x => x.Text == "DeserializeObject").FirstOrDefault();
List<SyntaxToken> NewTokenList = new List<SyntaxToken>()
        {
            desiToken
        };

var tokenList = SyntaxFactory.TokenList(NewTokenList);
var newNode =node.InsertTokensAfter(tokenList[0],new[]{SyntaxFactory.ParseToken("<"),SyntaxFactory.ParseToken("T"),SyntaxFactory.ParseToken(">")} ); 
//"node" is of type MethodDeclarationSyntax
```

But this doesn't seem to work, Nothing is happening, newNode doesn't have the modified code.

Also the reason I'm creating `SyntaxTokenList`, after digging a lot I found that the `SyntaxToken` has to be part of a `SyntaxTokenList`, otherwise it throws exception

Below is another way I tried After I realized that Span information is starting from zero

```
var xyz = SyntaxTokenList.Create(desiToken);
```

Even though now the span information is coming correctly, It throws the exception "System.InvalidOperationException:

> 'The item specified is not the element of a list.'

like before.

I couldn't find any blog/video related to this, can anyone show me the correct way

Answer (score -1):

The Roslyn syntax trees are immutable; InsertTokensAfter returns the new node with the change you've requested.

Comment: My bad, I've edited it. But still it doesn't fix the said issue.